# Angular and Lumen dont want to communicate via PUT Request

Tags: angular, laravel, routes, lumen, angular-httpclient

I have built a Rest API interface with Lumen, which should be addressed with Angular HTTP Requests.

Now the problem is that if I address the route `/api/blog` with PUT, I get a 405 method not allowed from Lumen. I have already written a middlware for CORS, which also allows methods, including PUT. I also use JWT for client authentication.

I need your help.

BlogInformationService:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {BlogInformation} from '../models/BlogInformation';

@Injectable()
export class BlogInformationService {
  private endPoint = environment.apiUrl + '/api/blog';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get<BlogInformation[]>(this.endPoint);
  }

  getByHash(hash: string) {
    return this.http.get<BlogInformation>(this.endPoint + '/' + hash);
  }

  create(blogInformation: BlogInformation) {
    return this.http.post(this.endPoint + '/add', blogInformation);
  }

  update(blogInformation: BlogInformation) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      })
    };
    return this.http.put(this.endPoint, blogInformation, httpOptions);
  }

  delete(blogInformation: BlogInformation) {

  }
}
```

Lumen Routing:

```
$router->group([
    "middleware" => [
        "authMiddleware",
        "secureBlogMiddleware"
    ]
], function ($router) {
    $router->post('/api/blog/add', ["uses" => "BlogController@addBlog"]);
    Route::put("/api/blog", "BlogController@editBlog");
});
```

Cors Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;


class CorsMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Method', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Middleware Config:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

$app->middleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class
]);
```

Request Header:

```
OPTIONS /api/blog HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed
Host: localhost:8000
Date: Fri, 04 May 2018 14:06:23 +0000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.4
Allow: GET, PUT
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Fri, 04 May 2018 14:06:23 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: can you put your controller code and the code of `app/http/kernel.php` as well ?

Comment: There is no app/http/Kernel.php

Comment: it's related to the jwt, you are using `authMiddleware`, which checks if the user is logged in, if not it will return response with 403, in other words you need to make sure the user is logged in & include the token in the request header

Comment: But why gives The Rest Server a 405 error and no 403?

Comment: make sure you are typing the path correct, to do this best try with postman

Comment: I tried it with postman and this works

Comment: then the issue not in laravel, it's in angular

Comment: Okay, but where? I am relative new in angular and dont know where the error can came from

Comment: other `post` and `get` requests are working in angular?

Comment: Yes, a normal get request works

Comment: add this header in angular and try: `'Accept':'application/json'` & `'Content-type':'application/json'`, also why there is no `Bearer` in header ?

Comment: tried and added bearer in authentication header but doesn't work...

Comment: can you update your answer including the changes you've made, also add the configuration for JWT, & the controller code?

Comment: I found the error. The Browser do a Options Request Instead of an put request. That was The Mistake. Now i Need to handle this.

Comment: this is not the issue, its a preflight request, it does this before the original request to check if the server accepts the headers..etc, the issue somewhere else

Comment: Real? But The Options Request fails with The http error „Method Not allowed“. I have now added options Route to lumen instead of The put request. Is there a another way to Check in lumen The headers with an options request?

Comment: check this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
Route::put("/api/blog", "BlogController@editBlog");
```

for

```
$router->put("/api/blog", "BlogController@editBlog");
```

Answer (score 0):

Lumen like Laravel cheats with PUT/PATCH etc requests. These need to be POST requests with the extra POST variable '_method' set to the request type (e.g.) PUT.

Comment: i have now a working solution. i will post the solution in the next days :)

Comment: @Lars can you please post your solution and tag me whenever you do, because im struggling to solve it, used URLSearchParams to encode the data but it has issues that i don't know how to solve yet